# Newly created record not appearing when called from relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a function which creates a new record in a model called "Onboarding". I want to then call this record via a "hasOne" relationship in the user model by doing `auth()->user()->onboarding` however this is returning null. Below is a snippet of my function where this is happening:

```
public function apiSend(StoreOnboarding $request)
    {
        //Update the user's Onboarding details on DB
        $this->store($request);

        //Validate user's onboarding details
        $validation = $this->checkValidation(auth()->user()->onboarding);

}
```

My store function:

```
public function store(StoreOnboarding $request)
{
    $onboarding = auth()->user()->onboarding()->updateOrCreate($request->validated());
}
```

My store function is working correctly and a new record of onboarding is added to the table, however in my `apiSend` function, I get an error:

**"Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\OnboardingController::checkValidation() must be an instance of App\Onboarding, null given".**

Below is a  snippet of my `checkValidation` function:

```
public function checkValidation(Onboarding $onboarding)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($onboarding->toArray(), [
    //Validation here
    ]);
}
```

And here is my onboarding relationship in the user model:

```
public function onboarding()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Onboarding::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

I don't understand why `auth()->user()->onboarding` is not returning the newly created onboarding record and instead returns null?

Comment: Where do you call your `checkValidation()` method?

Comment: @JohnHalsey the same controller as where my `apiSend` and `store` functions are (`OnboardingController`)

Comment: Have you set `belongsTo` relation in `Onboarding` model?

Comment: @Tpojka I have.

Comment: It looks like you're validating after you store onboarding record in the DB, according to your `apiSend()` method.  Is that right?

Comment: @JohnHalsey Yes i am attempting to validate the onboarding record which just got stored in the DB.

Comment: @Graeme this seems like a bad practice.  Surely you should do all your validation first, then just save it.  That way you know all your data it clean.

Comment: @JohnHalsey There is an option to "save as draft" in this form which does have validation (via the `store` function) but it is all nullable as the user can come back later and edit/fill in the rest of the form and this data is stored in the DB. The `apiSend` function uses its own separate validation to ensure all the required fields are filled. This is why validation is completed twice. One to store to the DB, and one to send via an API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more research, I found this can be resolved by doing

```
auth()->user()->load('onboarding');
```

just before using `auth()->user()->onboarding`

This forces the relationship to refresh.